# How to achieve an input impedance of 600 ohm for a balanced audio signal?

Tags: audio

How to achieve an input impedance of 600ohm for a balanced audio signal with 25Vpk input and with 13.15dB attenuation?

Comment: Please add more information with other requirements. Otherwise people will suggest something and then you say it does not fit your requirements.

Comment: Narendra, if you are done here you should formally accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Place a 600 ohm resistor between your two signal inputs. Pay attention to the power rating of the resistor if your input signal is indeed 25 Vpk.

You can serially divide this 600 ohm resistor into a string of 3 resistors, to achieve the attenuation. E.g. make the middle resistor 150 ohm and the two others 225 ohm each. This would cut the amplitude to 1/4, equalling ~12 dB attenuation. For -13 dB slightly reduce the middle resistor until it fits.

Another common way would be with a transformer that has 600 ohm primary impedance and steps down the voltage accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your support I will check and come back to you

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, a 600R resistor will do it. BUT please note that this is only generally done for testing puposes. For instance, a line output stage might be specified at "0.01% THD+N at +20dbU out, 1kHz". Then you want a 600R resistor for making the measurement, if you want to check it. (Most audio test sets will include such an option internally.) However, actual terminating impedance of 600R is never used in the real world. Typically line inputs are 10k-100k, mic inputs around 2k.

So where does the 600R number come from? Well, in the old days of telephony, a drive circuit would directly drive a long line, which consisted of two wires about 30cm apart. And it seems that 600R is more or less the characteristic impedance of such an arrangement. These days it's not relevant, but - the number has stuck around in specifications and the like. More on that [here](https://www.canford.co.uk/TechZone/Article/CableImpedance).

I point this out because it appears that you are reading these numbers from a spec sheet somewhere. Also note that the attenuation of your circuit is pretty much independent of output impedance. (Of course you could design a passive balanced attenuator with 3 resistors, the centre one being 600R and an attenuation to meet your question. The calculation of the other value is left as an exercise.)

Comment: +1 for a little more realistic context ;) But I think the 600 ohm actually matters. At least some years ago, when I read about making a mic preamp, I read that the lowish (matched) input impedance is relevant because using a normal high-Z input for mics would provide too little damping for them and, as a result, lead to resonant peaking in frequency. I never bothered to think more seriously about it though.

Comment: every mic pre I've seen uses an input impedance of about 2k. I think that mics and also good quality mic transformers expect that these days, it's a de-facto standard. You are right that a mic pre with 470k input would not be a good idea. That might be used for a high-Z guitar/bass input though.

Comment: I'm saying 2k from memory, this guy has about 6k (2 3k3 resistors, minus a bit for the transistor input stage). The SSM2017 chip he mentions has very high input R but in the app notes they show external resistors creating also an impedance <10k. At any rate, it is usually on the low side but not as low as 600R. https://sound-au.com/project66.htm

Comment: Thanks for the info dan!

Answer (score 0):

> *How to achieve an input impedance of 600ohm for a balanced audio
> signal with 25Vpk input and with 13.15dB attenuation?*

It sounds to me like you want to have a 600 Ω input impedance and maintain a 600 Ω output impedance whilst facilitating the required attenuation of 13.15 dB.

So, 13.15 dB attenuation is a gain reduction of 0.22 and here's a [taper-pad calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Taper%20pad%20attenuator.html) (from my boring website) that gives you resistor values to suit: -

[image]

So, the numbers above are for an unbalanced signal so, split R1 and R2 each into two resistors (of half but equal value) and duplicate on both input and output wires: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/attenuators/t-pad-attenuator.html) and note that splitting R3 into two equal resistors is not necessary for all applications and you may choose to ignore that.